# Siri Shortcut integration in Apple watch

Tags: apple-watch, siri, sirishortcuts

What i want to achieve is i am developing one app which gives store list located all over the world. I want to implement one feature in which when i say Siri to search near by stores than it redirect me to the my app with filter of near by stores in 10 miles so can you please guide me is there any other way  to achieve it?

I have try to achieve this using siri shortcut. I have iphone 6s (OS 13.3.1). I have created Siri shortcut both manually and programatically which work perfectly in my iphone but when i try to access same shortcut in paired watch (Series 4, OS 5) it gives me error "I do not recognise that command".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug with Siri for watchOS, I would report it in Feedback Assistant with logs attached.